# Replace string between two strings unless it contains a substring

Tags: python, regex

I have a multiline string with three of the following lines of the following form:

```
Text1 Text2a Text3
Text1 Text2b Text3
Text1 Text2! Text3
```

I wish to replace all texts between `Text1` and `Text3` with `Text4`, unless the intermediate text contains the character `!`. Thus, the desired output is:

```
Text1 Text4 Text3
Text1 Text4 Text3
Text1 Text2! Text3
```

Let `c` be the multiline string above. I believe `re.sub` is the natural choice for this problem, so I tried the following:

`c = re.sub("Text1(.*?)(?!=\!)Text3", "Text1 Text4 Text3", c, flags=re.DOTALL)`

However, it replaces every intermediate text with `Text4`. That is, I get the following output:

```
Text1 Text4 Text3
Text1 Text4 Text3
Text1 Text4 Text3
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Note the 1st capturing group, `(.*?)`, matches all characters including **!**, before Text3, thus the negative lookahead won't have any remaining characters left to prevent the match.

Comment: I would go with this `"(?<=Text1)([^!]*?)(?=Text3)"g`, look around for our boundaries and capture everything between that not includes `!`. https://regex101.com/r/o97cBR/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a `negative lookahead` to achieve your results. Matching anything except `!` character would do just fine. Modifying your regex as follows fixes the issue:

```py
c = re.sub("Text1([^\!]*?)Text3", "Text1 Text4 Text3", c, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

You can play with it online [here](https://trinket.io/python3/ecc7a5c717) and understand more about the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/D1mOjT/1).

Comment: Thank you. Can this approach be generalised to substrings? For instance, replace all intermediate text unless it contains the substring `abcde`.

Comment: For strings, `negative lookahead` is the go to. So something like `/Text1((?!.*?abcd).*)Text3/` would do the job. Try it for yourself [here](https://regex101.com/r/U5RwMy/1).

Answer (score 1):

I would phrase this as:

```py
import re

c = """Text1 Text2a Text3
Text1 Text2b Text3
Text1 Text2! Text3"""

c = re.sub("^Text1(?: [^\s!]+)+ Text3$", "Text1 Text4 Text3", c, flags=re.M)
print(c)
```

This prints:

```
Text1 Text4 Text3
Text1 Text4 Text3
Text1 Text2! Text3
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern used:

- `^` from the start of the line (`re.M` is multiline mode)
- `Text1` match "Text1"
- `(?: [^\s!]+)+` then match one or more non whitespace terms NOT containing `!`
- `Text3` match space and "Text3"
- `$` end of the line

Comment: Thanks Tim. Can you advise on how can generalise this approach to substring instead of characters? For instance, replace all intermediate texts unless it contains the string `abcde`.

Comment: You may use this pattern: `^Text1(?: (?!\S*abcde)\S+)+ Text3$` ... here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DyJ4N2/1)

Answer (score -1):

Use the less greedy `.*?` pattern to match as little text as possible before attempting to match the next pattern to resolve this problem. You can also use a positive lookahead assertion `(?=! )` to determine whether the `!` character is present in the intermediate text, as in the following example:

```
import re

c = """Text1 Text2a Text3
Text1 Text2b Text3
Text1 Text2! Text3"""

c = re.sub(r"Text1(.*?)(?=\!)Text3", "Text1 Text2! Text3", c, flags=re.DOTALL)
c = re.sub(r"Text1(.*?)Text3", "Text1 Text4 Text3", c, flags=re.DOTALL)

print(c)
```

Comment: This nonsense answer must have been generated by an AI: it has coding errors in it, and doesn't even begin to do what it says it does, let alone solve the asker's question.